Why is Apple Remote Desktop laggy over Thunderbolt?
While I'm setting up my new MacBook, I had a Studio Display in a more ergonomic posture which I plug my new Mac into. Therefore I need some way of controlling the old MacBook (which is out of reach) while having the contents on the studio display.
I'm trying to use Apple Remote Desktop. I have connected the two MacBooks using a USB 4/Thunderbolt 3 wire, setup Thunderbolt bridge, and entered the self-assigned IP address of the old Mac.
However, there is still considerable delays and lag, especially if I move to the highest resolution. USB4/Thunderbolt 3 can drive a Studio Display, so bandwidth shouldn't be the main/only factor here.
Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Should I be using another software that is specifically optimized for screen control/sharing over Thunderbolt/ethernet?
